# How to disable MUI Grid items from stacking when window width is smaller than 600px

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the MUI `Grid` component to make a layout. I placed two grid items next to each other and one below it. However when I resize the window and the width becomes smaller than `600px` the two grid items next to each other will stack. Does someone know where I can disable the two grid items stacking under `600px` window width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the default breakpoint values [here](https://mui.com/customization/breakpoints/#default-breakpoints) to know what `xs` or `sm` is. In `Grid` item, `xs={12} sm={6}` means that when the screen is smaller than `sm` (`600px`), grid item spans 12 columns (100% width), when it's smaller than `md` and larger than `xs`, grid item spans 6 columns (50% width)

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
    <Item>xs=12 sm=6</Item>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
    <Item>xs=12 sm=6</Item>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12}>
    <Item>xs=12</Item>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**Edit:** To disable stacking when the width is smaller than `600px`:

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
  <Grid item xs={6}>
    <Item>xs=6</Item>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={6}>
    <Item>xs=6</Item>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12}>
    <Item>xs=12</Item>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]